# WCF Service windows authentication

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2010, wcf-security

a WCF Service in hosted in our internal server. an external client will consume it and, our Service will consume our SharePoint service in order to edit an item list.
The WCF Service will have the automatically earn the windows authentication to access to the SharePoint site so I do not have to provide a login and password not domain name.

I am not sure how I am supposed to code my service:

```
NetworkCredential credential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

will be enough?

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEEp9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But if you do need to use a specific account you could go for the following:

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("name", "password", "optional:domain");
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it should be enough, if your wcf and SharePoint services in same (or trusted) domains, and you select appropriative security mode.

See for more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836.aspx